# There is no BuildConfig.DEBUG on Android

Tags: android

I created a new Android project and found out that I cannot use the next piece of code:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   //code
}
```

I tried to find another way to get Debug mode flag on the internet, but I didn't find a new solution, only a very old one.
What is the alternative to the BuildConfig.DEBUG flag?

Comment: Did you build the project at least?

Comment: @cmak Sure, I built and rebuilt the project

Comment: Does it compile? It may show a red warning but still compile. If not, try cleaning, then invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: @cmak It cannot be compiled because the BuildConfig class doesn't exist. I cleaned, invalidated caches, and restarted Android Studio and I've got the same result :( 
There is no problem in an older project (the version of Gradle is 7.5). Maybe the issue is connected with Gradle. I use the 8.0 version of the project.

Comment: Could be many things, are all the gradle related plugins updated too?, try compiling first without using the class and see if it gets generated, if not, try adding inside `android` in the `build.gradle` this `buildFeatures{buildConfig = true}`

Comment: @cmak `buildFeatures{buildConfig = true}` works. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the issue is the last version of Gradle: 8.0.
Thanks to @cmak I found out the next solution: the in build.gradle file of an app, add the `buildFeatures { buildConfig = true }` flag.

Comment: Glad it worked, but it's strange, as this should be enabled by default. Does the project happen to contain `android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig = false` in the `gradle.properties` file? That could be the actual issue

Comment: @cmak I think it happens due tor the last version of Gradle. I've updated Gradle's version in an older project and I got the same issue.

Comment: Funny thing, it just happened to me, never had this issue, ended up using this "trick". Must have something to do with Gradle or Android Studio updates